# Segfault while accessing dynamicly allocated C struct array

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I have the following struct that is defined in the following way

```
typedef struct _abcd {
    int a;
    unsigned long b;  
    void (*c)(int);
    int d;
} abcd_t, *abcd;
```

Now i have the following code

```
static abcd foo

int set_size(int size){
   foo = malloc(sizeof(abcd) * size);
}
```

This code for some reason gives me segfault when accessing some of the properties of array members.
But i have noticed that if i change the malloc line to the following - it fixes the issue

```
foo = malloc(sizeof(foo[0]) * size);
```

I find it strange as obviously `sizeof(foo[0]) = sizeof(abcd)`
So what is exactly the difference here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> obviously `sizeof(foo[0]) = sizeof(abcd)`

It is not the same since you `typedef`ed `abcd` to be a *pointer* to `struct _abcd`.

Use

```
foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo) * size);
```

to have robust code even if the type of `foo` should change at some point.

Your

> ```
> foo = malloc(sizeof(foo[0]) * size);
> ```

is essentially the same since `foo[0]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(foo + 0)` which becomes `*foo`.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is you're allocating `sizeof(abcd)` and that's a pointer, not a struct.  You want `sizeof(abcd_t)` or `sizeof(*abcd)`.